# How I can solve the ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1?

Tags: python, installation, package, pycaret

I'm trying to install the package "Pycaret" and work with a Windows on the AWS environment.
While I have been able to successfully install other libraries I get an error when I try to install Pycaret.

```
!{sys.executable}  -m pip install pycaret --user
```

Here is the error message:

ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
command: /home/ec2-user/anaconda3/envs/python3/bin/python /home/ec2-user/anaconda3/envs/python3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip install --ignore-installed --no-user --prefix /tmp/pip-build-env-x1mgp31u/overlay --no-warn-script-location --no-binary :none: --only-binary :none: -i https://pypi.org/simple -- 'setuptools>=40.8.0' wheel
cwd: None
Complete output (14 lines):
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/home/ec2-user/anaconda3/envs/python3/lib/python3.6/runpy.py", line 193, in _run_module_as_main
"**main**", mod_spec)
File "/home/ec2-user/anaconda3/envs/python3/lib/python3.6/runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
exec(code, run_globals)
File "/home/ec2-user/anaconda3/envs/python3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip/**main**.py", line 23, in 
from pip._internal.cli.main import main as _main  # isort:skip # noqa
File "/home/ec2-user/anaconda3/envs/python3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip/_internal/cli/main.py", line 5, in 
import locale
File "/home/ec2-user/anaconda3/envs/python3/lib/python3.6/locale.py", line 16, in 
import re
File "/home/ec2-user/anaconda3/envs/python3/lib/python3.6/re.py", line 142, in 
class RegexFlag(enum.IntFlag):
AttributeError: module 'enum' has no attribute 'IntFlag'

ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: /home/ec2-user/anaconda3/envs/python3/bin/python /home/ec2-user/anaconda3/envs/python3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip install --ignore-installed --no-user --prefix /tmp/pip-build-env-x1mgp31u/overlay --no-warn-script-location --no-binary :none: --only-binary :none: -i https://pypi.org/simple -- 'setuptools>=40.8.0' wheel Check the logs for full command output.

Comment: Can you try upgrading pip and setuptools ?

Comment: `pip install -U pip setuptools`

Answer (score 0):

Run
`$ pip uninstall enum34`
and run the command again.

Answer (score 0):

Upgrade setuptools

`pip install -U pip setuptools`